# Render from fbo texture to another within same fbo

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

I'm trying to set up deferred rendering, and have successfully managed to output data to the varying gbuffer textures (position, normal, albedo, specular).

I am now attempting to sample from the albedo texture to a 5th colour attachment in the same fbo (for the purposes of further potential post process sampling), by rendering a full screen quad with simple texture coordinates.

I have checked that the vertex/texcoord data is good via Nsight, and confirmed that the shader can "see" the texture to sample from, but all that I see in the target texture is the clear colour when I examine it in the Nsight debugger.

At the moment, the shader is basically just a simple pass through shader:

vertex shader:

```
#version 430

in vec3 MSVertex;
in vec2 MSTexCoord;

out xferBlock
{
    vec3 VSVertex;
    vec2 VSTexCoord;
} outdata;

void main()
{
    outdata.VSVertex = MSVertex;
    outdata.VSTexCoord = MSTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(MSVertex,1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) uniform sampler2D colourMap;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 colour;

in xferBlock
{
    vec3 VSVertex;
    vec2 VSTexCoord;
} indata;

void main()
{
    colour = texture(colourMap, indata.VSTexCoord).rgba;
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing fancy about the shader.

The gl code is as follows:

```
//bind frame buffer for writing to texture #5
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4); //5 textures total
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//activate shader
glUseProgram(second_stage_program);

//bind texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_buffers[2]); //third attachment: albedo

//bind and draw fs quad (two array buffers: vertices, and texture coordinates)
glBindVertexArray(quad_vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);
```

I'm trying to work out what is preventing rendering to the texture. I'm using a core context with OpenGL v4.3.

I've tried outputting a single white colour for all fragments, using the texture coordinates to generate a colour `colour = vec4(indata.VSTexCoord, 1.0, 1.0);` and sampling the texture itself, as you see in the shader code, but nothing changes the resultant texture, which just shows the clear colour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *scratches head* a vertex shader that does NOT write to `gl_Position`?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that, thanks, for pointing it out. Didn't fix the problem though.